# flat JSON to struct with nested properties

Tags: json, swift, decodable

All questions I have found so far on the searches I've done is about decoding nested JSON to some struct with nested properties. I want to do the opposite: decode **flat** JSON to a struct with nested properties.

Here's example JSON:

```
{
    "id":"ABC123",
    "cell":"test",
    "qty":24
}
```

which I'd like to decode to this struct:

```
struct InventoryItem {
    let id: String
    let mfgInfo: MfgInfo
}

extension InventoryItem {
    struct MfgInfo {
        let cell: String
        let qty: Int
    }
}
```

I have tried adding CodingKeys for each struct:

```
struct InventoryItem: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let mfgInfo: MfgInfo

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, mfgInfo
    }
}


struct MfgInfo: Decodable {
    let cell: String
    let qty: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case cell, qty
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. I get this error:

> No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"mfgInfo\", intValue: nil) (\"mfgInfo\"), converted to mfg_info.

How can I make this work without a custom initializer? Or do I need to write a custom `init(with: Decoder)` initializer?

Comment: There is a full example for this in the documentation provided by Apple: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types

under "Encode and Decode Manually"!

Comment: @Mamaessen, I read that documentation, but it appears to deal with encoding nested JSON to a flat struct. I'm trying to do the opposite (flat JSON to nested struct).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to do this without implementing the `init(from: Decoder)` initializer, but it was easier than I thought. For nested structs that just have primitive types, you can just use the automatically synthesized `init(from: Decoder)` method.

Final struct setup:

```
struct InventoryItem: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let mfgInfo: MfgInfo

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
    }

    struct MfgInfo: Decodable {
        let cell: String
        let qty: Int

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case cell, qty
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        id = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id)
        mfgInfo = try MfgInfo(from: decoder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible with a custom `init(with: Decoder)` implementation, or by having e.g. a `FlatInventoryItem` type that conforms to `Decodable` and then providing conversion methods between that and your desired `InventoryItem` type.

Comment: This is kinda what I thought, but I was hoping there was a more concise way.